# python intersect of dict items

Tags: python, intersect

Suppose I have a dict like:

```
aDict[1] = '3,4,5,6,7,8'
aDict[5] = '5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12'
aDict[n] = '5,6,77,88'
```

The keys are arbitrary, and there could be any number of them. I want to consider every value in the dictionary.

I want to treat each string as comma-separated values, and find the intersection across the entire dictionary (the elements common to all dict values). So in this case the answer would be '5,6'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce # if Python 3

reduce(lambda x, y: x.intersection(y), (set(x.split(',')) for x in aDict.values()))
```

Comment: ok now i'm getting error: TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API. Any ideas? What if the is just 1 dict entry? What happens then?

Comment: just as a guide the actual dict with 1 entry looks like:- {4: b'1,2,31,47,52,56'}. This is what is causing the error.

Comment: @khany I haven't worked with Python 3, but I think [this](http://www.rmi.net/~lutz/strings30.html) will be helpful. BTW, if you are Python newbie and you don't have any special reasons for 3rd version, I highly recommend using Python 2, it is mainstream version today.

Comment: hmm I was using v3 to future proof my code but I am now looking into v2.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to convert these to real lists.

```
l1 = '3,4,5,6,7,8'.split(',')
```

Then you can use sets to do the intersection.

```
result = set(l1) & set(l2) & set(l3)
```

Comment: incomplete answer as the dict has an indeterminable length

Answer (score 1):

Python `Set`s are ideal for that task. Consider the following (*pseudo* code):

```
intersections = None
for value in aDict.values():
    temp = set([int(num) for num in value.split(",")])
    if intersections is None:
        intersections = temp
    else:
        intersections = intersections.intersection(temp)

print intersections
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @khany: What version do you use? It is a standard function since Python 2.2: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems

Comment: @khany It's because of Python 3, you should have mentioned that in your question.

Comment: @khany: depending on your version, you can also use `dict.items()`, this should work quite as good.

Comment: @Constantinius Do you really need `items()` here? You don't use `key` at all.

Comment: @DrTyrsa: correct. I'll change the answer. (Got mixed up, because my first attempt was to create a `dict` of `set`s, which was a stupid idea as I have found out).

Comment: @Constantinius yes it is Python 3.1 sorry I forgot to mention that. I hadn't marked your answer down though.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = None
for csv_list in aDict.values():
    aList = csv_list.split(',')
    if result is None:
        result = set(aList)
    else:
        result = result & set(aList)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `set.intersection()` accepts any number of sets, you can make do without any use of `reduce()`:

```
set.intersection(*(set(v.split(",")) for v in aDict.values()))
```

Note that this version won't work for an empty `aDict`.

If you are using Python 3, and your dictionary values are `bytes` objects rather than strings, just split at `b","` instead of `","`.